# When running " python mnist_with_summaries.py ", it has occurred the error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, mnist

1. When running this example：" python mnist_with_summaries.py ", it has
   occurred the following error:
2. detailed errors：

   > Traceback (most recent call last):
   >     File "mnist_with_summaries.py", line 214, in 
   >       tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
   >     File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py"
   >   , line 48, in run
   >       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
   >     File "mnist_with_summaries.py", line 186, in main
   >       tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.log_dir)
   >     File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.p
   >   y", line 367, in recursive_create_dir
   >       pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
   >     File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 89, in **exit**
   >       next(self.gen)
   >     File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors
   >   _impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
   >       pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
   >   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: /tmp\tensorflow
3. Running environment：windows7+Anaconda3+python3.6+tensorflow1.3.0
4. Why?Any idea on how to resolve this problem?Thank you！

Comment: Looking at what could cause `Failed to create a directory: /tmp\tensorflow` on your system would be a good start... Looks like it's expecting a *nix structure like filesystem and you're running on Windows... so maybe some config changes?

Comment: `/tmp\tensorflow` looks like Linux.

Comment: I've just begun to get my head around tensorflow. And I'm reading the book that it's called Tensorflow in TechnologyAnalysis and Action. When I run examples according to the book, I have this problem.

Comment: I read the code, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

- I have solved this problem.
- I changed *line 204* and *line 210* of *mnist_with_summaries.py* to the *local directories*, and I created some folders.
- **OR**, don't change the code, and I created some folders in the local disk where is the running environment according to the code.

  - line 204: create */tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data*
  - line 210: create */tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/mnist_with_summaries*